# Invalid variant operation error when trying to store Integer in TJvFormStorage

Tags: delphi, variant, delphi-10.1-berlin, jvcl

In a VCL application in Delphi 10.1.2, I use a `TJvFormStorage` component to persistently store and restore data.

So in **JvFormStorage1** at design-time I have created a **StoredValue** to hold an `Integer` value:

[image]

Then at runtime, I try to assign an `Integer` value to this **StoredValue**:

```
JvFormStorage1.StoredValue['ToolbarLabelFontSize'].Value := 8;
```

This causes an **Invalid variant operation error**!

But as you can see from the screenshot above, the **Value Type** of the **StoredValue** is explicitly defined as `Integer` type!

So how can I assign an `Integer` value to this **StoredValue**?

Comment: I don't use JEDI myself, so I can't test, but try the following. Since `JvFormStorage1.StoredValue['ToolbarLabelFontSize']` is a `variant` as such, remove the `.Value` you now have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StoredValue[]` property provides [access to the variant values directly](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvFormStorage.StoredValue), so the correct way to set the value of one of these values would be:

```
JvFormStorage1.StoredValue['ToolbarLabelFontSize'] := 8;
```

Comment: I followed your advice and now there is no more error message. But instead of **8** it stores the value of **71** in the XML file: `<ToolbarLabelFontSize>71</ToolbarLabelFontSize>`!! But when RESTORING it gets again **8** with `Integer(JvFormStorage1.StoredValue['ToolbarLabelFontSize']))`?? How are the values **8** and **71** transformed into each other?

Comment: To answer my previous comment, it seems that not the `Integer` value is stored in the XML file but the `Variant` value is stored in the XML file.